# Where are actual databases stored in Debian Linux Server

Tags: linux, debian

Our system crashed and we're trying to recover our data. The disc is
fine but the OS is gone, so I'm trying to get at the actual mysql
databases document. Does anybody know where to look for them in a
Debian linux server

Comment: They are wherever you configured mysql to put them.

Answer (score 2):

Should be in /var/lib/mysql... By default!
Note it is easy for an Admin to set the dB location else where, and if you can't figure that kind of information out, then you have a big problem with your procedures/ documentation you should address before any technical issue!

Btw, 30 secs of googling would have given you the answer...

Answer (score 1):

By default, the database directory is `/var/lib/mysql` and set in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. 
Look for the line `datadir         = /var/lib/mysql` to confirm.